# Replacing faulty disk in a Supermicro server

Tags: hard-drive, supermicro

I have a Supermicro server model: X9DR3-F.
The server acts as a ESXi host with a Windows 2012R2 server on top of it all.

The server has 22 disks in a RAID-50, with disk 22 being the hot spare.

I have two faulty disks in the RAID and I need to replace them.

**I would really appreciate some help with how to do this. Can I just remove the faulty disks and install two new ones and would the RAID rebuild itself? Or do you have to do it some other way?**

I have tried to install Intel Rapid Storage (RST) utility but I can't find a version that can be installed on the windows server, could it be that it's not recognized as a Supermicro since it's a virtual machine?

I have searched for days for answers but can't find any.

Comment: Virtualization is a problem indeed if you need some software tool to recognize the host's hardware. Typically is isn't seen in the VM, only the virtualized hardware as presented by the virtualization software.

Comment: IMO, you'd have a better chance of getting a better answer at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: With 22 disks, there is no way those are all handled by the onboard controller on the server motherboard. So it will be important to know what exact model of add-on RAID controller is being used.

Comment: Did you lose 2 disks in the same set? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment